# How to read fopen() errors

Tags: php

It seems that whatever I try, I don't get data in a fifo file.

```
$fifo_action = fopen( "/tmp/fifo_action", "w+" );
    die( "first fifo fail" ); 
$fifo_value = fopen( "/tmp/fifo_value", "w+" );
    die( "second fifo fail" );

fwrite( $fifo_value, $id );
fwrite( $fifo_action, "ly" );

fclose( $fifo_value );
fclose( $fifo_action );
```

Whatever I try, I get "first fifo fail" as result. The fifo's exists. I tried to chmod them in 777. I can write to the fifo from c++. Even if I login as the www-data user in my terminal.

At this time, I have no clue on how to proceed further. Is there a way to output the exact error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running the `die()` regardless of what happens in the first `fopen()` so it is bound to tell you it has failed.

`fopen()` will return `false` if it fails so you have to test for that. Note the use of `===` which is also important when a function can return a good status that might also be interpreted accidentally as false.

```
$fifo_action = fopen( "/tmp/fifo_action", "w+" );
if ( $fifo_action === false){
    die( "first fifo fail" ); 
}
$fifo_value = fopen( "/tmp/fifo_value", "w+" );
if ( $fifo_value === false){
    die( "second fifo fail" );
}

fwrite( $fifo_value, $id );
fwrite( $fifo_action, "ly" );

fclose( $fifo_value );
fclose( $fifo_action );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your die statement is executed regardless the result of fopen.

```
$fifo_action = fopen( "/tmp/fifo_action", "w+" )
if (!$fifo_action) die( "first fifo fail" ); 
$fifo_value = fopen( "/tmp/fifo_value", "w+" )
if (!$fifo_value) die( "second fifo fail" );

fwrite( $fifo_value, $id );
fwrite( $fifo_action, "ly" );

fclose( $fifo_value );
fclose( $fifo_action );
```